# Cannot set a valid PHP executable path in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, validation, visual-studio-code

I choose the 7.0.19 version since that what MAMP is using.

Here is how the settings for PHP looks like in Visual Studio Code right now:

```
{
"window.zoomLevel": 0,    
"php.validate.enable": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "D:\\Software\\MAMP\\bin\\php\\php7.0.19.exe",
"php.validate.run": "onType",
"[php]": {         

}
```

}

And here is an error message:

```
Cannot validate since D:\Software\MAMP\bin\php\php7.0.19.exe is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: I have the same problem. It refuses everything

Answer (score 1):

You need to change
"D:\Software\MAMP\bin\php\php7.0.19.exe"

to:

"D:/Software/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.19.exe"

and it will work.

Comment: Add this above all (with complete path to php exe): 
"php.executablePath": "path-to-your-php-exe",

Example: "php.executablePath": "D:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64\\php.exe",